# Using a DP3T Toggle On-On-On to switch between two devices and then have them both on

Tags: voltage-regulator, toggle-switch

I have a DP3T on-on-on switch that I would like to use to switch the power from my bicycle dynamo hub to front light on position 1, rectifier/regulator on position 2 and then both light and rectifier/regulator on position 3.

The positive and negative leads would go directly to the switch but I don't know which pins to connect them to nor do I know which pins to bridge.

I am using this switch https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/toggle-switches/7109876/ by TE Connectivity which has six pins to connect to. If you can provide a diagram that would be very helpful to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the switch [drawing](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1825139&DocType=Customer%20Drawing&DocLang=English)..which took forever to find..

[image]

**Jumper:**

```
Pin 3 to Pin 5. (Note 5 on Drawing)
```

**Use:**

```
Pin 3 : To Dynamo
Pin 4 : To Light,
Pin 2 : To rectifier/regulator ,
```

Though you could switch the latter two.

**Switch function will be**

```
Left - Rectifier
Centre - Both
Right - Light
```